# Can we test Apple pay in simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, ios9, applepay

I know that Apple pay testing we use Apple pay stubs in iOS 8, but please let me know how to use Apple pay without ApplePayStubs in iOS 9 in simulator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is working in Simulator with Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

No need for bio metric thumb scanning.

Thanks all

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You can test apple pay using iOS 9 simulator. So you don't need to add any testing sheet instead PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController. It's working on iOS 9 simulator. Make sure your app run on iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus or latest version of simulator.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. The simulator Apple Pay flow won't return a valid payment token, which could cause some people to trip up!

Comment: but how ? any step .

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 12.5 and iOS 14.5 you can do that using

<kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/Authorization.html

> NOTE
>
> In Xcode 7.0 or later, you can test the payment authorization view
>   controller in the simulator. It provides simulated cards for all the
>   supported payment networks and returns dummy payment data in plain
>   text. On a device, this data is encrypted with your merchant
>   identifier and must be decrypted either on your server or by your
>   payment processor.
>
> Use the Apple Pay Sandbox environment to test your app on a device
>   with test cards.
>
> Although these techniques provide fast and convenient ways to test
>   your code, you still need to thoroughly test Apple Pay on actual,
>   physical devices with production cards.