# Setup Apple Pay in iOS 17 simulator

Tags: ios, applepay, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to setup Apple Pay pay as shown in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/) for sandbox testing. I've created a testing user, and setup its country as US. In the simulator I've setup the region as US as well.  I log in with the testing account on the simulator.

If I go to my app and try to purchase something I see this

[image]

So I can make purchases, but if I go to settings and try to click on

*"Payment & shipping"* or *"Media & Purchases"* it asks for my credentials/password and nothing happens or it says that *"iTunes account creation not allowed"* - *"This Apple ID cannot be used with the iTunes Store at this time"*.

[image]

If I try to add a card in wallet I get *"Could not set up Apple Pay"*

Should this work on simulator or am I trying something impossible?

I'm using xcode Version 15.0.1 (15A507), simulators with iOS 17 on them.

Comment: The test process you linked to is for real devices.  For Simulator testing, see the duplicate

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answer my question. I can't add cards as it says in the duplicate, as i've mentioned in my question :) and also the documentation linked to that is very old

Comment: You can’t add cards in the simulator. You don’t need to. You just use the menu item to provide a successful Apple Pay event.

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020722/3418066)